# Find array elements and replace column in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, replace

I have a matrix `A` of size 13472x1537. This matrix contains values smaller than 1. In my case I seek for a solution to satisfy the following condition:
If a column contains a value smaller than 1, replace all other values in the same column with `NaN`.

I was able to implement a code that could replace these values (smaller than 1) with the previous value (or any value). However, I am looking for a solution that changes every value in the column to `NaN` no matter whether later (or previous) values are greater than 1.

I have `i=1537`; `t=13472`

```
for i = 1:size(A,2) 
    I = A(1,i);
    for t= 2:size(A,1)
        if A(t,i) <= 1
           A(t,i) = I;
        else
        I = A(t,i);
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: What is the desired behaviour when there are multiple values smaller than 1 in one column?

Comment: @DennisKlopfer: okay I should have specified the problem. If there is at least one value smaller than 1 in a column, all values in the column should return NaN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A version, which gets rid of the loop would look like this:

```
A = randn(5)+2; % Random example
[row,col] = find(A<1);
A(:,col) = NaN;
```

If you would want to keep the values smaller than 1 in the matrix a solution could look something like this:

```
A = randn(5)+2; % Random example
[row,col,ind] = find(A<1);
b = A(ind)
A(:,col) = NaN;
A(ind) = b;
```

Comment: This solution works in a sense that it identifies all values smaller than 1. Yet having your random example and a 5x5 matrix, it returns a 1x5 vector. Would it be possible to obtain a 5x5 matrix that returns the actual values for the cells no smaller than 1? Or would you suggest to use the "repmat" function and work with an if-statement in a way: if A==0 return value from original matrix? Maybe you have a solution in mind that is smoother?

Comment: `A` is still a 5x5 Matrix containing all the values smaller than 1. I don't really understand your question. Can you clarify which output you want as a Matrix instead of a vector? I'm not sure how you want to use `repmat` in this case? I edited the second part of the code a bit to use less memory space.

Answer (score 1):

That would be like the following

```
for i = 1:size(A,2) 
    if ~isempty(find(A(:,i) <= 1))
        A(:,i)=nan(size(A,1),1);
    end
end
```